# Drupal reset password: Fatal error

Tags: php, drupal-7, view

When I create a account on my website, then I get a email with instrutions to set a password. When I click on the link, than I get a login button. I can only click one time on it. But when I click i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function access() on a non-object in
>   /sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 497

I didn't change anything in the PHP code (NEVER!). I hope someone has a answer for me.

Comment: Show us the code in the line 497 of your php script.

Comment: Problem is solved. The commerce module is the issue. Deleted it and install the ubertcart module.